# WPF UniformGrid rows and column same width height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, uniformgrid

i need help with UniformGrid, or Grid, table, whatever.

**Simple Version:**
I have a MainWindow with only 6 Rectangle, and they should fill my entire MainWindow. When i resize the window, those 6 Rectangle need to able to resize and keep the same width and height like all the other rectangles.

I eventually need to replace my rectangles with actual content, such as 6 videos playing, or 6 web browsers, or 6 images, etc, all with same width/height, as the window resizes by the user.

Here are the rectangles.

[image]

Here is my XAML code so far. It doesn't quite work, as even if i resize the MainWindow, the rectangles all stay as "squares", they always have length = width. But i need rectangles, with sometimes the length could be greater than width, since he window is resized by user however he wants.

```
        <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="3">
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Black" />
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Green" />
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Yellow" />
            <Rectangle Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="Orange" />
        </UniformGrid>
```

**Complex Version:**
I eventually need to allow user to display 1, 2, 4, or 6 displays, so they need to take up the entire window with width/height.

Here's how it would look if it should display 2 display. (when the user resize the window so that length > width)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid give's you that resizing behavior already if you define your columns and rows with star-size, which is the default. Instead of writing for example `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` you can just write `<RowDefinition/>`.

So, this should work:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Black" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Red" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Green" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Yellow" />
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Orange" />
</Grid>
```

For the complex case you need to adjust the Grid's `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` based on the elements that you put into that `Grid` and based on Window size, if you want to create columns or rows. You can set everything from Codebehind on the Grid.

Give it a name in Xaml and use in Codebehind for example `grid.RowDefinitions.Add(...);`

Add or remove elements in Codebehind via `grid.Children.Add(...);`

Set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` in Codebehind via static methods `Grid.SetRow` and `Grid.SetColumn`

Comment: Thanks, this works, but do you know why if i wrap the whole thing in a <StackPanel> and it doesnt work? I guess that was really my problem, was that i have nested dockpanels and stackpanel all over the place and somehow this code once inside a stackpanel does not work at all.

Comment: Yes, when you have a vertikal StackPanel, nothing can be stretched vertically, because, well, the StackPanel stack things vertically :-) Elements will be only stretched horizontally in a vertical StackPanel. 

The other way around is a horizontal StackPanel: Elements can be stretched vertically, but horizontally they're not stretched, as they're stacked.

That's it.

If you want that your elements grow and shrink, use the <Grid> and define columns and rows. Those columns with * size will grow and shrink.

Comment: The DockPanel has a LastChildFilll property that you can set to true, then the last child will grow and shrink when you resize the whole DockPanel, but only that last child.

The Grid is the real thing that you want to use. Use nested Grids, and you're fine.